# SSL and IIS "Cannot find the original signer" - p7b file

Tags: ssl, iis, wildcard-subdomain

I created a request for a wildcard certificate from my provider and was given .p7b file (PKCS#7 Binary). When importing this .p7b into IIS, I get "***Cannot Find the Original Signer***".  I have installed other certificates from same company with no issues but this wildcard certificate is giving me headaches. I feel like I'm missing something?

Through MMC I have added the certificate successfully and edited it to add a friendly name - a fix I read about - but it did not change anything. I still get the same error message. I can't seem to find anything else with enough info to get me going.

Comment: Have you checked the certification chain with an external tool?

Answer (score 0):

Double click the certificate and click the Certification Path tab. If there is a certificate in the chain that is missing, you will see it there. Then you just have to find and install that certificate. The issuer would almost certainly be able to supply you with it.

Comment: All say "This certificate is ok."  Looking at the certificate they sent it does say...Common Name is  *.[mydomain].com and Subject Alternative Names is *.[mydomain].com. Is that an issue? Should the common name just be [mydomain].com and the SAN be *.[mydomain].com? I'm really stuck...